# how to create in template in django application

Tags: python, django, windows

I am following the tutorial on polls application,now am in part 3 but got confused on how to create a template so that Django’s template system separates the design from Python
by creating a template that the view can use. The basic instruction is as follow: "First, create a directory called templates in your polls directory. Django will look for templates in there The default settings
file configures a DjangoTemplates backend whose APP_DIRS option is set to True. By convention
DjangoTemplates looks for a “templates” subdirectory in each of the INSTALLED_APPS.
Within the templates directory you have just created, create another directory called polls, and within that create
a file called index.html. In other words, your template should be at polls/templates/polls/index.
html. Because of how the app_directories template loader works as described above, you can refer to this
template within Django as polls/index.html." Now my question is how do I create this because I understand the whole of the tutorial? I need someone to come down to my level as a beginner. Thank you.

Comment: Templates are _created_ with a text editor application, such as vi or notepad.  But this seems like an extremely basic question, even for a beginner.  Was your question really "Where should template files be located", or "What should a template file look like"?

Comment: Yes,I want to know where the template file should be located and template file look like as well.

Comment: Inside your `polls` directory, create a `templates` directory. Inside that, create another  `polls` directory, and inside that, create your `index.html`. Putting those parts together, you get the path `polls/templates/polls/index.html`, as it shows in the tutorial. The tutorial tells you what to put in the `index.html` template, right after *Put the following code in that template:*.

Comment: If you're new to Python and the command line, you might find the Django Girls tutorial easier than the official Django tutorial. The Django girls tutorial covers some basics like how to create directories in the [introduction to the command line section](introduction to the command line section).

Comment: I really appreciate Alasdair,the Django Girls  tutorial you introduced to me has been helpful and I have been able to create those directories with ease. Kudos!